# Online Video tutorials or good books on Protocols

Tags: documentation, protocol

I wanted to understand protocols and their basic functioning in depth, specially i am focussing on SIP and MEGACO/H.248 these days..

So, i wanted to have some links where I can find good tutorials or specially video tutorials on these protocols for free...

PS: Please any type of help or guidance will be appreciated..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In general a good place to look up protocols is here: http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc.html. This is the website for RFCs. If you don't know what an RFC is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_Comments.

Comment: Yes, all web/internet protocols should have an RFC available.  Those are the official sources.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the info in http://www.protocols.com/.